# Responsive container height

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I set up the slideshow on this site to be responsive but now I need the container height to adjust with the image inside.

http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/test/

HTML:

```
<div id="feature">
    <div class="topshadow clearfix" style="position: relative; width: 1113px; height: 335px;">
        <div class="feat_box first" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 10; opacity: 0; width: 1113px; height: 325px;">
            <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Company-Photo_MF-RE-Page-Slide-Show.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feat_box" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 10; opacity: 0; width: 1113px; height: 325px;">
            <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/New-Home-Page-Photo-copy-2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feat_box" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 10; opacity: 0; width: 1113px; height: 325px;">
            <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/iStock_000016899532Medium.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feat_box" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 10; opacity: 0; width: 1113px; height: 325px;">
            <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/iStock_000018818618Medium.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feat_box" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 10; opacity: 0; width: 1113px; height: 325px;">
            <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/iStock_000002082925Medium.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feat_box" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 10; opacity: 0; width: 1113px; height: 325px;">
            <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/golf2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feat_box" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 10; opacity: 0; width: 1113px; height: 335px;">
            <div class="textwidget">
                <p><img src="http://yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Sunnyside-015.jpg">
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feat_box" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 10; opacity: 0; width: 1113px; height: 325px;">
            <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/iStock_000018294410Medium.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feat_box" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 10; opacity: 0; width: 1113px; height: 325px;">
            <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/cars.1200.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feat_box" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 11; opacity: 1; width: 1113px; height: 325px;">
            <div class="textwidget"><img src="http://www.yourwhiteknight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/balloons-1200.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like it is the `.topshadow` class, but I am not sure what should be put in here.

Comment: You're better off starting with a script that has flexible height from the start. There are plenty of them. Trying to retrofit gets very messy. CSS on its own won't do the trick, as the JS will keep interfering.

Comment: Or maybe you want the image to fit the container instead? So it won't overflow?

Answer (score 0):

use vw on your height and width so it will take a percentage of the screen width opposed to having a fixed px height and width. Also setting a fixed height and width could be overriding the classes you are putting on it, so use responsive values like vw, vh, or %, or don't give them  a height and width and let your classes take care of all that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a flexible div like this:

HTML

```
<div id="flex"> Your slider </div>
```

CSS

```
div#flex { width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0px; max-width: initial; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took Geckob's comment and added a new slider to the theme that is responsive. Thank you all for your suggestions but this seemed like the easiest solution.